# Let X be a set and let $ \tau_1 $ and $ \tau_2 $ topologies over X. Show that if (X, $ \tau_1 $) e (X, $ \tau_2 $) are compact Hausdorff spaces...

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness

i)Let X be a set and let $ \tau_1 $ and $ \tau_2 $ topologies over X. Show that if (X, $ \tau_1 $) e (X, $ \tau_2 $) are compact Hausdorff spaces, then $ \tau_1 $ = $ \tau_2 $ or $ \tau_1 $ and $ \tau_2 $ are incomparable.

ii) Let {$ X_i: i \in I $} be a family of compact Hausdorff spaces . Show that $ \sigma $ is a topology over the set $ \prod_ {i \in I} X_i $ that makes all projections and ($\prod_ {i \in I} X_i, \sigma $) is compact, so $ \sigma $ matches the product topology on $ \prod_ {i \in I} X_i $.

---

My attempt at i) went like this

Assume that $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$. Then the identity map: (X,$\tau_2$)→(X,$\tau_1$)is continuous. Let C be closed in $\tau_2$, so, X\C $\in \tau_2$. Since $\tau_2$ is compact,C is compact as a subspace of $\tau_2$. Because continuous maps map compact sets to compact sets, C is also compact as a subspace of $\tau_1$. But $\tau_1$ is Hausdorff, so this means that C is closed in $\tau_1$. We showed that every closed set in $\tau_2$ is closed in $\tau_1$, so $\tau_2 \subset \tau_1$ and therefore $\tau_1 =\tau_2$.
Similarly if we instead assume $\tau_2 \subset \tau_1$, the same argument also shows $\tau_1 =\tau_2$.

I'm having bigger troubles with ii)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For ii), just apply i) to $\sigma$ and the product topology. Well, you need to show that $\sigma$ is Hausdorff first, but that's immediate once you see the relation between $\sigma$ and the product topology that you need before applying i).

Comment: In (i) you are proving  a special case (proved in the same way) of the result that a continuous bijection from one compact Hausdorff space to another is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in order to apply $i)$, you just need to show that $\sigma$ is Hausdorff (the product topology is compact by Tychonoff).

We just want to prove that if all the projections are continuous and each $X_i$ is Hausdorff, then $\sigma$ is Hausdorff.

Indeed, let $x\neq y\in \prod_{i\in I} X_i$ and fix some $j$ such that $x_j\neq y_j$. Since $X_j$ is Hausdorff, there exist open sets $U,V\subseteq X_j$ such that $U\cap V$ is empty and $x_j\in U$ and $y_j\in V$. Now, let $\pi_j:\prod_{i\in I}X_i\to X_j$ denote the corresponding projection. Then, $\pi_j^{-1}(U)\cap \pi_j^{-1}(V)=\emptyset$ and by continuity of $\pi_j$, both of these sets are open. Furthermore, clearly $x\in \pi_j^{-1}(U)$ and $y\in \pi_j^{-1}(V)$. Thus, $\sigma$ is Hausdorff.